# Реализация сервера на Java

Tags: java, сервер

У меня есть приложение на Java, которое реализует многопоточный локальный сервер и также умеет брать значения из базы данных MySQL(также локальной). Вопрос заключается в том, что как бы теперь сделать так, чтобы этот сервер работал в интернете. То есть идея в том, что пользователи используют мобильное приложение, с помощью сервера они получают информацию из базы данных. Спасибо.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону Spring

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо:

1. Сервер, доступный из интернета. Самый сложный способ - собственное железо, собственный IP etc. Это сложно и дорого, обычно такое делают только очень крупные компании с миллионами и миллиардами на счетах. Обычные люди и компании арендуют сервера у хостинг-провайдеров. Берите любого провайдера, вооружайтесь доступом по ssh и настраивайте сервер. Вам здесь нужен будет VPS сервер.
2. После настройки сервера (установки всех нужный программ (Java, СУБД, иэб-сервер (Tomcat/nginx/apache2))) - запускайте на VPS-сервере вашу программу.
3. (Опционально) Купите и подключите домен к IP адресу, данному хостинг-провайдером. Подключите https к домену.

Answer (score 0):

Можно перечислить такие варианты:

- аренда VPS сервера / выделенного сервера. На минимальном железе обойдется в 300-500 р./мес. Понадобятся навыки администрирования ос, например, Linux
- использование хостинга, поддерживающего java приложения (н-р: Heroku, Amazon Web Services - частично бесплатные). Разобраться будет проще, чем в первом варианте, но бесплатные варианты очень ограниченные
- покупка физического сервера / использование пк в качестве сервера